# Deploying Node JS application over a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I have done quite a research of deploying an application over the local server that I have on my machine. Each source code for the Node JS application or the example that is available over the internet specifies to run the application from the console.

Is there any way that i can configure my MAMP server so that when i hit a URL the Node code specified is executed. 
Are there any parameters to set for the same ?
I looking forward to the steps to achieve this as i was not able to found a relevant answer for the same as such.

Comment: Node doesn't work with a MAMP server normally -- you'd set it up to listen on its own ports, etc (and if not done correctly, you'll end up conflicting with port 80 if you don't do a reverse proxy). You probably just want to run Node as a daemon or service. There's quite a few web pages that discuss it.

Comment: Google for "mod_rewrite for node.js" http://kevnls.blogspot.com/2012/01/running-nodejs-alongside-apache.html http://readwrite.com/2010/12/23/how-to-run-apache-and-nodejs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Node.js (for real-time notifications) to an existing PHP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472687/adding-node-js-for-real-time-notifications-to-an-existing-php-application)